# MySQL Keeps Forgetting Root Password Used to Install

Tags: mysql, mysql5

I'm using the MySQL Installer on Windows 8.1. I go through the installation steps for MySQL Server, including setting my password. However, when I go back to reconfigure my server through the Installer or attempt to login to the server through MySQL Command Line Client, it tells me I have the wrong password.

I have installed and reinstalled multiple times to no avail. My password has just letters (uppercase and lowercase) and spaces.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL Docs provide instructions on how to change your root password:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html